# Changing or eliminating Header & Footer in TCPDF

Tags: php, pdf-generation, tcpdf

`AddPage()` in tcpdf automatically calls Header and Footer. How do I eliminate/override this?

Answer (score 76, accepted):

Use the `SetPrintHeader(false)` and `SetPrintFooter(false)` methods before calling `AddPage()`. Like this:

```
$pdf = new TCPDF(PDF_PAGE_ORIENTATION, PDF_UNIT, 'LETTER', true, 'UTF-8', false);
$pdf->SetPrintHeader(false);
$pdf->SetPrintFooter(false);
$pdf->AddPage();
```

Comment: This answer didn't really help me for what I wanted to do. I wanted **only the first page** to have no headers or footers... THIS http://queirozf.com/reminders/tcpdf-how-to-print-a-page-with-no-header-or-footer is what I did in the end.

Answer (score 13):

A nice easy way to have control over when to show the header - or bits of the header - is by extending the TCPDF class and creating your own header function like so:

```
  class YourPDF extends TCPDF {
        public function Header() {
            if (count($this->pages) === 1) { // Do this only on the first page
                $html .= '<p>Your header here</p>';
            }

            $this->writeHTML($html, true, false, false, false, '');
        }
    }
```

Naturally you can use this to return no content as well, if you'd prefer to have no header at all.

Comment: I tried this first using `$this->getAliasNumPage()` which didn't work, this did though. Cheers Lukey

Answer (score 2):

Here is an alternative way you can remove the Header and Footer:

```
// Remove the default header and footer
class PDF extends TCPDF { 
    public function Header() { 
    // No Header 
    } 
    public function Footer() { 
    // No Footer 
    } 
} 

$pdf = new PDF();
```

Answer (score 1):

> How do I eliminate/override this?

Also, [Example 3 in the TCPDF docs](http://www.tcpdf.org/examples/example_003.phps) shows how to override the header and footer with your own class.

Answer (score 1):

**Example:**
 - First page, no footer
 - Second page, has footer, start with page no 1

**Structure:**

```
    // First page
    $pdf->startPageGroup();
    $pdf->setPrintFooter(false);

    $pdf->addPage();
    // ... add page content here
    $pdf->endPage();

    // Second page
    $pdf->startPageGroup();
    $pdf->setPrintFooter(true);

    $pdf->addPage();
    // ... add page content here
    $pdf->endPage();
```

Comment: For Header: 
$pdf->setPrintHeader(false); // hidden
$pdf->setPrintHeader(true); // visible

Answer (score 0):

```
// set default header data
$pdf->SetHeaderData('', PDF_HEADER_LOGO_WIDTH, 'marks', 'header string');

// set header and footer fonts
$pdf->setHeaderFont(Array(PDF_FONT_NAME_MAIN, '', PDF_FONT_SIZE_MAIN));
$pdf->setFooterFont(Array(PDF_FONT_NAME_DATA, '', PDF_FONT_SIZE_DATA));
```

With the help of above functions you can change header and footer.

Comment: Thanks for your belated answer.  I had wanted to eliminate the Header/Footer, and Brian's way did it.