# Unwanted lines in TCPDF class with custom header and footer

Tags: php, pdf, tcpdf

I'm using TCPDF to generate pdf reports. I need custom headers and footers, so I extended the original class to overwrite the Header and Footer methods as suggested in the official documentation (https://tcpdf.org/examples/example_002.phps).

Here you are the code:

```
class AppPdf extends \TCPDF {

    CONST LOGO_PATH =  '/../../../public_html/public/images/logo-big.png';

    private $xLogo;
    private $yLogo;
    private $wLogo;

    public function __construct($orientation='P', $unit='mm', $format='A4', $unicode=true, $encoding='UTF-8', $diskcache=false, $pdfa=false, $xLogo = 8, $yLogo = 0, $wLogo = 50) {
        parent::__construct($orientation, $unit, $format, $unicode, $encoding, $diskcache, $pdfa);

        $this->xLogo = $xLogo;
        $this->yLogo = $yLogo;
        $this->wLogo = $wLogo;
    }

    public function Header() {
        $this->Image(__DIR__ . self::LOGO_PATH, $this->xLogo, $this->yLogo, $this->wLogo);
    }

    public function Footer() {
        $this->SetXY(34,260);
        $this->SetFont('Helvetica', 'I', 8);

        $this->SetTextColor(0, 0, 0);
        $this->MultiCell(130, 20, "footer text", 0, "C", false);
    }

}
```

Then I have a base template that it is used for all the generated documents:

```
class BasePdf {

    CONST CREATOR = 'Creator';
    CONST TITLE = 'Title';
    CONST PDF_FONT_NAME_MAIN = 'Times';
    CONST PDF_FONT_SIZE_MAIN = 11;

    protected $pdf;

    public function __construct($xLogo = 8, $yLogo = 0, $wLogo = 50)
    {
        $this->pdf = new AppPdf('P', 'mm', 'A4', true, 'UTF-8', false, false, $xLogo, $yLogo, $wLogo);
        $this->pdf->SetCreator(self::CREATOR);
        $this->pdf->SetAuthor(self::CREATOR);
        $this->pdf->SetTitle(self::TITLE);

        $this->pdf->SetFont(self::PDF_FONT_NAME_MAIN, "", self::PDF_FONT_SIZE_MAIN);
    }

    public function getPdf()
    {
        return $this->pdf;
    }
}
```

The base template is used as shown in the following class:

```
use AppBundle\Entity\HPVExam;

class HPVReport extends BasePdf
{
    public function __construct(HPVExam $HPVExam)
    {
        parent::__construct(8, 10, 75);

        $this->pdf->AddPage();
    }
}
```

The problem is that this code generates pdfs with an annoying horizontal line in the top and another one in the footer, as you can see in the following image [image: example of the unwated lines in my pdfs].

I have already tried the suggestions provided here [PHP / TCPDF: Template Bug?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3422876/php-tcpdf-template-bug) and here [Changing or eliminating Header & Footer in TCPDF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2217132/changing-or-eliminating-header-footer-in-tcpdf) but without luck.

What I'm doing wrong? It seems that the original Header and Footer methods are not correctly overwritten... Any idea? Thank you!

Comment: Maybe use only `Cell` instead of `MultiCell` - https://tcpdf.org/examples/example_003.phps

Comment: No, I have completely removed everything from the header except the logo and the lines are always there...

Comment: Have you tried using a different browser to view the PDF? It might be browser specific

Comment: Yes and this is not the case.

Answer (score 1):

Just say to TCPDF that dont print the header or go and modify the source....

```
$pdf->SetPrintHeader(false);
```