# PHP TCPDF remove header's bottom border

Tags: php, tcpdf

I am trying to create a header in TCPDF, however it always have a border underneath of it. Is there a way I can remove the bottom border?

Comment: class MYPDF extends TCPDF {
    public function Header() {
        $image_file = K_PATH_IMAGES.'pdf-header.jpg';
        $this->Image($image_file, 160, 10, 40, '', 'JPG', '', 'T', false, 20, '', false, false, 0, false, false, false);
        $this->SetFont('helvetica', 'B', 10);
    }

    public function Footer() {
        $this->SetY(-15);
        $this->SetFont('helvetica', 'I', 8);
       
    }
}

Comment: try the code above should eliminate the problem

Comment: An alternative which doesn't involve editing the tcpdf class or extending it is presented in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2217132/changing-or-eliminating-header-footer-in-tcpdf)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

tcpdf.php:

```
// print an ending header line
$this->SetLineStyle(array('width' => 0.25 / $this->k, 'cap' => 'butt', 'join' => 'miter', 'dash' => 0, 'color' => array(255, 255, 255)));
```

Comment: This is not the answer. In common case if no data added into header and footer it's better to disable header and footer, that is pointed in other answers here.

Comment: A bit old, but still can't understand why this was chosen as the right answer

Comment: Make sure to also have a look at the approach of `András` below.

Answer (score 134):

This works for some versions:

```
// Call before the addPage() method
$pdf->SetPrintHeader(false);
$pdf->SetPrintFooter(false);
```

Comment: This works fine but I would like to specify what these lines must be added before calling AddPage() method.

Comment: I think there are other default values

Comment: Not sure why the above answer was marked as correct, this is the correct answer. Thank you.

Comment: There is no configuration constant to tell that to TCPDF? Because this means you have to put these 2 lines for every TCPDF usage, which can be painful if you have several PDF exports

Comment: @Xenos You can always subclass TCPDF and override the `->AddPage()` calling those two lines, and then calling the parent.

Comment: @XaviMontero which means I'll have to change all TCPDF instantiation in favor of the subclas instance... It's a way to bypass this issue but this can only be done before using TCPDF, and no afterward (when poor legacy architecture wasn't already using a subclass nor a central factory)...

Comment: @Xenos Well... if the code is "very legacy" and does a "new" all over there, I see one fast way to change this: Make your class to also be named TCPDF but locate it in another namespace such as `\MyApp\Pdf`. Then search for all the files containing `new TCPDF` or there any static usages `TCPDF::` and just at the beginning of the file place `use \MyApp\Pdf\TCPDF`. I'd would be great to use Dependency Injection if you could; but in the meantime you refactor, this does the trick.

Answer (score 38):

If you don't want to subclass or change the tcpdf source just call the `setHeaderData` method and specify white line color.

```
$pdf->setHeaderData('',0,'','',array(0,0,0), array(255,255,255) );
```

Comment: This actually answers the question. If you are, however, looking to completely disable the Header and Footer (like I was), then the answer from @András is what you want.

Comment: Not worked for me dear, still showing a horizonal row / line in header section of pdf. Thanks.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17172044/10329023    solution worked for me. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Problem solved by extends the TCPDF class and modify the header and footer.

```
class MYPDF extends TCPDF { 

    public function Header() 
    { 
        $image_file = K_PATH_IMAGES.'pdf-header.jpg'; 
        $this->Image($image_file, 160, 10, 40, '', 'JPG', '', 'T', false, 20, '', false, false, 0, false, false, false); 
        $this->SetFont('helvetica', 'B', 10); 
    } 

    public function Footer() 
    { 
        $this->SetY(-15); 
        $this->SetFont('helvetica', 'I', 8); 

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the other solutions posted in this thread does not work, I solved in this way:

**TL;DR**
In Footer() function in Tcpdf class (tcpdf.php):
Replace this lines:

```
$this->Cell(0, 0, $pagenumtxt, 'T', 0, 'L'); // line 3527 in version 6.3.1
$this->Cell(0, 0, $this->getAliasRightShift().$pagenumtxt, 'T', 0, 'R'); // line 3530 in version 6.3.1
```

With this lines

```
$this->Cell(0, 0, $pagenumtxt, 0, 0, 'L');
$this->Cell(0, 0, $this->getAliasRightShift().$pagenumtxt, 0, 0, 'R');
```

**Alternative way 1**
Comment this lines in Footer() function in Tcpdf class (tcpdf.php):
In my file (version 6.3.1) they were placed at line 3524

```
//Print page number
if ($this->getRTL()) {
    $this->SetX($this->original_rMargin);
    $this->Cell(0, 0, $pagenumtxt, 'T', 0, 'L');
} else {
    $this->SetX($this->original_lMargin);
    $this->Cell(0, 0, $this->getAliasRightShift().$pagenumtxt, 'T', 0, 'R');
}
```

This will disable the render of the page number in the footer but at least it removes the unwanted line.

**Alternative way 2**
If these methods does not work, search in the tcpdf.php file for this string:

```
$this->SetLineStyle(array
```

You should find 3 occurrences, replace the 'color' property of the array with the value `[0,0,0]` (or the rgb color of your background), this should cause the line to turn white (or the color you set).
I used this method to troubleshoot where the problem was by putting custom weird color and seeing which one was being rendered.

**Explanation**
The line is rendered because in the lines

```
$this->Cell(0, 0, $pagenumtxt, 'T', 0, 'L');
$this->Cell(0, 0, $this->getAliasRightShift().$pagenumtxt, 'T', 0, 'R');
```

The border property is set to 'T' (top border). You can disable the border by set the border property to 0 ([see docs here, $border param](https://tcpdf.org/docs/srcdoc/TCPDF/classes-TCPDF/#method_Cell)).
If that doesn't work you can entirely disable the render of the page number (and thus the border), or you can set the border to a custom color that matches you actual background.

Answer (score -1):

Comment this line in Header() function of tcpdf Class :

```
$this->Cell(($this->w - $this->original_lMargin - $this->original_rMargin), 0, '', 'T', 0, 'C');
```