# How to customize tcpdf header and footer?

Tags: header, customization, footer, tcpdf

KIndly share the customization procedure  tcpdf header section  and footer section?

Answer (score 3):

Set Header .

```
$PDF_HEADER_LOGO = "logo.png";//any image file. check correct path.
$PDF_HEADER_LOGO_WIDTH = "20";
$PDF_HEADER_TITLE = "This is my Title";
$PDF_HEADER_STRING = "Tel 1234567896 Fax 987654321\n"
. "E abc@gmail.com\n"
. "www.abc.com";
$pdf->SetHeaderData($PDF_HEADER_LOGO, $PDF_HEADER_LOGO_WIDTH, $PDF_HEADER_TITLE, $PDF_HEADER_STRING);
```

Set Footer .
**Open tcpdf.php file and search the "public function Footer()"**
Now in this function **see the last else condition,** and you can add your code there
E.g

```
$this->SetX($this->original_lMargin);
$footer_data="Abc Company Pvt Ltd XYZ 20 000 111 222 USA credit Licence Number 000000";
$this->Cell(0, 0, $this->getAliasRightShift().$footer_data, 'T', 0, 'L');
$this->Cell(0, 0, $this->getAliasRightShift().$pagenumtxt, 'T', 0, 'R');
```

Answer (score 1):

Partially covered by: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12672014/279262

You can customise header/footer in such a way:

```
class MyTCPDF extends TCPDF
{
   public function Header()
   {
      // Customised header
   }
   public function Footer()
   {
      // Customised footer
   }
}
```